# Criar blob de imagem no PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Como eu posso criar um blob de uma imagem no PHP e retornar para o JS?
Já tentei usar o `file_get_contents()` retornando para o jQuery e criar um objectURL mas obviamente não funcionou.

Comment: Seria legal [edit] a pergunta e mostrar o código que tentou. Pode ter sido falta de algum pequeno detalhe. Se postar um [Mcve] com a parte JS, fica melhor ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver convertendo a imagem de URL para sua versão normal talvez você esteja incluindo o cabeçalho `"data:image/*;base64,"`, ele vai acabar impedindo que a imagem seja lida, além de ser desnecessário. Se for isso, basta fazer algo tipo isso antes de decodificar a string em base64: `substr(imageURL, strpos(imageURL, ',') +1)`, e talvez possa estar resolvido.

Outro possível erro: talvez você possa estar recebendo o conteúdo dessa imagem da forma errada. `URL.createObjectURL` requere o primeiro argumento como instância de `Blob`. Talvez o tipo de resposta do seu `XHR` (se você estiver usando) não é `"blob"`, então basta fazer algo como `(xhr.responseType = "blob")`, antes de `xhr.send();`, daí: `URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response)`.

Respondendo a pergunta, tente:

(PHP)

```
<?php

/* responde o client-side com o conteúdo binário da imagem */
echo file_get_contents("image.png");
```

(JavaScript (o `jqXHR` do jQuery não oferece `"blob"`))

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('GET', "*.php", true);
/* define a resposta do tipo "blob" */
xhr.responseType = "blob";

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var file = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);

        } else /* erro de requisição */ ;
    }
}; xhr.send();
```